# Perl: reading file into a hash and splitting, retrieving information

Tags: perl, hash

I have a file which has data like this:

```
1        unknown    state   3204563 3207049 .   -   .   name "gosford"; school_name "gosford"; pupil_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";
```

I want to read it line by line into a hash, and then split it with regular expressions. so that i can count the number of schools.]

so far i have:

```
my$schools;
open (SCHOOLS, <"$schools) or die (Cannot open $schools");
while <SCHOOLS> {
chomp;
my ($val, $key) = split /(^\d)\s+\w+\s+\W+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\.\s+\+\s+\.\s+.. and so on);
}
```

How do I get the values I've split into the hash, and then manipulate them so produce some basic statistics?

Comment: Counting the number of schools, shown in terminal.

Comment: Remove `split`. You're using match here, not splitting. After that get groups you're interested in in `()`.

Comment: Are you literally just trying to get the count of schools?

Comment: Counting the number of schools is just one of the tasks id like to do. I am using split.

Comment: Many things are really unclear. What does one line in your input describe? What do you actually want in your hash? Do you have any idea of what split does (your usage suggests you don')?

Comment: We could really use a bit more sample data, some samples of headings, and more exact examples of what you're trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're after, but I will offer - you are doing things the hard way using a long regex to match the line. Also, for 'other things' it's quite hard to tell exactly what you have in mind. But `grep` is your friend, as it lets you specify search terms.

Something like this will do the trick. I've used a simplistic example for counting entries matching a particular criterion. Of course, given you've only given us one row, this is a bit of a guess:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

my @entries; 
my @keys = qw ( id thing state firstnum secondnum ); 

while ( <DATA> ) { 
   my %attributes = m/(\w+) "(\w+)"/g;
   @attributes{@keys} = split;     
   push @entries, \%attributes; 
}

print Dumper \@entries; 

print "count of things: ", scalar @entries, "\n";
print "There are ", (scalar grep { $_ -> {state} eq "state" } @entries), " things with a state of 'state'\n";

__DATA__
1        unknown    state   3204563 3207049 .   -   .   name "gosford"; school_name "gosford"; pupil_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";
```

I'll also point out - it's much better form to use lexical filehandles with 3 arg open. E.g.

```
open ( my $schools, '<', 'schools.txt' ) or die $!; 
while ( <$schools> ) { 
     #etc.
}
```

I'm using the special filehandle `__DATA__` for illustrative purposes.